# Getting a strange error in the web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Getting strange ERROR in web app.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSPNote: sun.tools.javac.Main has been deprecated.
error: An error has occurred in the compiler; please file a bug report (http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi).
1 error, 1 warning
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:262)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspServlet.loadJSP(JspServlet.java:465)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspServlet$JspServletWrapper.loadIfNecessary(JspServlet.java:149)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspServlet$JspServletWrapper.service(JspServlet.java:161)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:274)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:387)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at com.xvsi.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:404)
    at com.xvsi.servlet.BVRequestDispatcher.forward(BVRequestDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.processActionForward(ActionServlet.java:692)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:584)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:147)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at com.xvsi.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:404)
    at com.xvsi.servlet.ServletContainer.processRequest(ServletContainer.java:348)
    at com.xvsi.servlet.ServletContextContainer.processRequest(ServletContextContainer.java:819)
    at com.xvsi.servlet.BVServletEngine.service(BVServletEngine.java:246)
    at com.xvsi.servlet.BVServletConnector.service(BVServletConnector.java:141)
```

Comment: That error occurred when transitioning from JDK1.3 to 1.4, i.e. ancient JDKs. What version of Tomcat are you running? At least try to move up to JDK1.5/Tomcat 6 or 7.

Comment: [Bug 33601](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33601).

Answer (score 0):

This usually means there is a syntax error or the like in your JSP page.  Without seeing more it's hard to advise.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to debug, unless you are able to recollect and revert the last few changes or deploy in portions to debug which jsp file has an issue.

I suggest use ANT to pre-compile the JSP as mentioned here .

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html

This is assuming that the JSP's have a problem.